# ReactJS: Stateful children in stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, children

Does having stateful children in a stateless component make the component no-longer stateless?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short answer

No, it doesn't.

---

The life-cycle methods that are associated with a component that has state should work independently of where they are in the component hierarchy, otherwise things would break in unpredictable ways.

Here's proof that stateless components have a backing instance of a class, so they can use `ref`s and life-cycle methods:

```js
class StatefulComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.wrapper.classList.add("highlight");
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={ref => this.wrapper = ref}>
        Stateful (red outline due to class being added)
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const StatelessComponent = props => (
  <div>
    Stateless (black outline)
    {props.children}
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <StatefulComponent>
    <StatelessComponent>
      <StatefulComponent />
    </StatelessComponent>
  </StatefulComponent>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
  outline: 1px solid;
}

.highlight {
  outline-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

State is a property privately managed by a component and hence a **component being stateless is decided by its own self** and not by its parents or children.

No lifecycle hooks are available within the stateless component whereas they continue to work as desired in their children.